# Is it "what in the seven hells" or "what in the nine hells"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

I see both but Google shows more results for nine hells, though I can't find definitely what those nine are supposed to be, whereas a list pops up for the seven different levels of hell.

Comment: People using expletives are not usually careful to comply with the details of the literary/cultural  tradition!

Answer (score 4):

It's both, depending upon your preference.

**Nine hells** is doubtlessly related to Dante's *Inferno* with its nine circles. It has been popularised in fantasy and gaming scenes by *Dungeons & Dragon*'s use of the Nine Hells as a dimension inhabited and ruled by devils (demons inhabited the 666 layers of the Abyss). [*Player's Handbook*, TSR, 1977, p.120] While I can't cite any hard sources, several online sources believe that D&D's use was inspired by Dante. D&D included an appendix of sources of a broad range so it's highly believeable the authors were aware of *Inferno* which isn't exactly an obscure work.

Seven hells has recently been popularised by [*A Song of Ice and Fire* or its *Game of Thrones* derivatives.](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Seven_hells) Why the author chose 7 I don't know but it's likely it's because of a long standing human interest with the number 7.

The concept of "seven heavens" goes back to Mesopotamia at the latest. It is seen in [Judaism](https://kabbalahcenter.net/seven-levels-of-heavens/) and [Islam](https://zamzam.com/blog/seven-levels-of-heaven/). Christianity does not explicitly mention 7 in in its canonical scriptures but it does occur in extra-canoncal works (Book of Enoch). Some people marry these seven heavens with the seven virtues/graces.

In opposition there are seven deadly sins and so a natural correspondence with seven hells is easy to infer, no?.

The Mesopotamian goddess [Inanna (elsewhere called Ishtar)](https://sacred-texts.com/ane/ishtar.htm) travelled through **seven hells** to find her lover Dumuzi (Tammuz), shedding one item of her royal clothing at each gate. Following on from there, [Judaism has seven hells](https://forward.com/culture/120547/how-many-circles-has-gehinom/) (Sheol, Abaddon, Beër Shahat, Tit ha-Yawen, Sha'are Mawet, Sha'are Zalmawet, Gehenna). Islam notes seven gates to the [hell realms](https://www.whyislam.org/islam/hell/) and uses seven names for hell in the Koran and there has developed a system of seven hells (Jahannam, Laza, Hutama, Sa'ir, Saqar, Jahim, Hawiya). Again, Christianity doesn't specify 7 hells.

While [Buddhist cosmology](http://buddhism.redzambala.com/buddhism/philosophy/hells-in-buddhism.html) typically depicts 8 hell realms there are various numbers used by various sources including 7 and 10 but not 9. , Jainism has 7 [hell realms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naraka_(Jainism))
which one is born into after performing bad actions, though eventually, as in Buddhism, one will leave them and be reborn elsewhere.

Comment: This would benefit from citing your sources.

Comment: Final Fantasy FXIV also has seven hells and many characters use that idiom. Or rather, they say "seven hells" as an expletive.

Answer (score 1):

In Dante's **[Inferno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dante))** - the first part of his epic poem **Divine Comedy** - there are nine circles of Hell:

Limbo, Lust, Gluttony, Greed, Wrath, Heresy, Violence, Fraud and Treachery.

I've only ever heard them referred to as the nine *circles* of Hell, not the nine *Hells*.